# Infering return type through conditional type of parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to infer the return type of the function via conditional types.
If the type and parameters extend a type, `AudioConfig<T>` for example - I want the return type to be `Audio<T>`, otherwise `Video<T>` and lastly never if type not found.

```js
interface Audio<T extends string> {}
interface Video<T extends string> {}

type AudioConfig<T extends string> = {
    type: 'Audio'
}
type VideoConfig<T extends string> = {
    type: 'Video'
}

type Params<T extends string> =
    | AudioConfig<T>
    | VideoConfig<T>

type Configuration<T extends string, P extends Params<T>> =
    P extends AudioConfig<T> ? Audio<T> :
    P extends VideoConfig<T> ? Video<T> :
    never

type InitConfigurationFn = <T extends string, P extends Params<T>>(params: P) => Configuration<T, P>

const initConfiguration: InitConfigurationFn = (params) => {
    switch (params.type) {
        case 'Audio':
            return { type: 'Audio' }
        case 'Video':
            return { type: 'Video' }
    }
}
```

Currently `initConfiguration` function is erroring:

> Type '<T extends string, P extends Params>(params: P) => { type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'InitConfigurationFn'.
> Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Configuration<T, P>'.(2322)

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIFcAmwD2AeAFWQgA9IRMBnZSsKUAcwD5kBvAXwChRJZEUAasEwR8RUuSo06jFh06cwATwAOKDNhwBhHCBjAGhYmQgVqteiGbIAvG07JHyZWoBcyAOQbcHzlxeCwqI6egZGEqZSFrK29k7OqhDuHkIiOL5cionIAApwUHAAtpThJmbSltY2Dk4APmhYuCH6hgRMNY71qcG6LYTtWWrIzQboBWC4IKWS5jJWADS5xjO5%20UUlbSzV8TnLkdTe2r1hbcgA-A2a-ciuHUsR5d1Hoa0sF0-Xt-EgEABu0AoAsgAJIgYBgEYMMZwCa6ABiIFi032FUYi12DykeQKxX6TAAFCo1sV3DkAJS2FiQ6GwqYEdEDBC6WjIUDg6njSbuUHs45QznwxF2QnEygUmxyO6UADu4IQAAtkCKcZQAHQBCmsO7xBBwSgoLyNdJfeKmxxQCBgMaI1gJNyeQ4eZBcM2OXX6zxPDwm11OC1WqA2u1JT1BdLOu5cdhAA)